# Android test-only permissions with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I run `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` and I need my test APK to have a permission which should not be in any non-testing APK (debug, release). I have created a manifest with permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mypackage">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE"/>
</manifest>
```

Then I have copied this manifest to `src/androidTest` directory, as [release notes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) from gradle android plugin suggest:

> 0.13.0 (2014/09/18)
>   Requires Gradle 2.1
>   It is now possible to provide a manifest for test apps (src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml)

However, the permission is not applied during my connected tests.

If I create a `src/debug` directory and move this manifest there -- the permission is applied correctly during connected tests (but also during regular debug builds, which is undesirable).

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem stems from my misunderstanding of how `connectedAndroidTest` gradle task works. It creates and deploys 2 android applications - a testable (your project) and a tester (an app which simulates a user who interacts with the testable app). My intent was to add the permission to the testable app. However, adding a manifest to `src/androidTest` resulted in adding the permission to the tester app. Here's how I figured that out:

If I execute

```
adb shell pm list packages -f -3
```

(`-3` means to list only third-party packages) I can see something like this

package:/data/app/SmokeTestApp.apk=com.android.smoketest
package:/data/app/GestureBuilder.apk=com.android.gesture.builder
**package:/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-2.apk=com.mycompany.myapp**
package:/data/app/SoftKeyboard.apk=com.example.android.softkeyboard
package:/data/app/org.libsdl.app-2.apk=org.libsdl.app
package:/data/app/SmokeTest.apk=com.android.smoketest.tests
**package:/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp.test-1.apk=com.mycompany.myapp.test**

The app with **test-1** suffix is the tester app, another one is my testable app. Checking their permission gives:

```
root@generic_x86:/ # aapt d permissions /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-2.apk

package: com.spredfast.android
uses-permission: android.permission.INTERNET
uses-permission: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

root@generic_x86:/ # aapt d permissions /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp.test-1.apk

package: com.spredfast.android
uses-permission: android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE
```

So the permission, `SET_ANIMATION_SCALE`, which I was intending to put into my testable app is put into the tester app. No wonder that moving the manifest from `src/androidTest` to `src/debug` would put the permission into the testable app (correct, but too broad).

---

Here's how I solved the original problem - putting the permission into the application **only** in case of the application being run inside `connectedAndroidTest` task.

1. I have created an empty build flavor to be used with integration tests:

   ```
   productFlavors {
       /**
        * This flavor is to be run only using connectedAndroidTestAnimcontrol
        */
       animcontrol {}

       regular {}
   }
   ```
2. Moved `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` with the single permission into `src/animcontrol/AndroidManifest.xml`
3. Executed connected tests as

   ```
   ./gradlew connectedAnimcontrolDebugAndroidTest
   ```

That did the trick, now I have `AndroidManifest.xml` which will be merged with main app's manifest only when being run as connectedAndroidTest.

Hope this helps someone.